# How to compare time strings in Bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to compare two time strings in bash script. For example, 09:00:00 should be greater than 06:00:00. I wrote some code like this:

```
if [[ $1 > $time_higherbound ]]
    echo "$1 > $time_higherbound"
fi
```

It turns out this approach does not work and I can get some example outputs like this:

```
09:00:01 > 09:00:00
09:00:01 > 10:00:00
09:00:01 > 24:00:00
09:00:01 > 17:00:00
09:00:01 > 24:00:00
```

Since I don't want the comparison include the date, I cannot use the comparison between timestamp. Does anybody know how to deal with this?

Comment: `[[ 09:00:01 > 24:00:00 ]] && echo yes` outputs nothing, indicating the first string is *not* greater than the second.

Comment: There's no `then` in your `if`. That code is invalid syntax; it couldn't possibly have emitted the output given.

Comment: Do not compare strings.  Convert them to a timestamp and compare numbers.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, *Why not* compare strings? If you use a well-chosen date format, its string sort order is identical to its numeric one.

Comment: @charlesDuffy Just general best practice.  Dates should only be represented as strings for presenting to humans.  For all other purposes, they should be treated as timestamps.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, re: "general best practice", (an appropriate subset of) ISO 8601 date formats are amenable to ASCII sort. I'd argue that anyone storing their dates in a format well-chosen in that manner *is* following general good practices. There are common cases where someone *must* store a date in ASCII (think filenames); having those filenames sort identically with the semantics of the date is important and valuable, making use of such formats good practice; and once one's following a practice that provides those guarantees, why not rely on them?

Comment: @Coding_Rabbit, I'd suggest looking into whether either of your strings contains hidden characters that could throw off the sort order. Running your script with `set -x` / `bash -x yourscript` to trace execution is often informative.

Answer (score 2):

#### A string comparison, like you were already doing, works fine for this purpose when your date string format is well-chosen.

Observe:

```
fixed_time=09:00:01
compare_times=(
  09:00:00
  10:00:00
  24:00:00
  17:00:00
  24:00:00
)

for compare_time in "${compare_times[@]}"; do
  if [[ $compare_time = $fixed_time ]]; then
    echo "$compare_time = $fixed_time"
  elif [[ $compare_time < $fixed_time ]]; then
    echo "$compare_time < $fixed_time"
  elif [[ $compare_time > $fixed_time ]]; then
    echo "$compare_time > $fixed_time"
  fi
done
```

...[properly emits as output](https://ideone.com/2p2djV):

```
09:00:00 < 09:00:01
10:00:00 > 09:00:01
24:00:00 > 09:00:01
17:00:00 > 09:00:01
24:00:00 > 09:00:01
```

Comment: I'm curious, why comparisons like `[ "8" > "9" ]` do not work the same way?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov, `[` is a regular command (even when implemented as a builtin, it has no special parser rules), so `>` inside it is a redirection operator, telling the output of `[` to be written to a file called `9`. Thus, you need to use `[[` (which is syntax), not `[`, to make `>` work unescaped/unquoted. (And using `>` in `[` at all is bad practice, because even though it works in bash with appropriate escaping/quoting, [POSIX doesn't guarantee it](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html); whereas code using `[[` explicitly supports only extended shells).

Comment: Ah, indeed! Thank you.

Comment: ...of course, the other thing to be aware of is that `[[ "10" > "9" ]]` won't have the same output as a numeric comparison without padding the strings to be of identical length (`[[ "10" > "09" ]]`).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert the date into seconds and compare that.

```
date1="$(date -d "$1" +%s)"
date2"$(date -d "$time_higherbound" +%s)"

if [ $date1 -gt $date2 ]; then
    echo "$date1 > $date2"
fi
```

You can also convert back to a typical date format

```
echo $(echo `date -d @$date1`)
echo $(echo `date -d @$date2`)
```

Comment: That will fail for ```24:00:00```.

Comment: just curious, is `24:00:00` a valid time?

Comment: @accdias – @Kent is right, `24:00:00` is not a valid time, though `23:59:60` [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second). GNU `date` (afaik unlike any other implementation of `date`) supports `-d STRING` and its implementation is pretty rock-solid for automatically understanding the various formats.

Comment: It looks like OP's logic is using 24:00:00 as start of new day "09:00:01 > 24:00:00". @Coding_Rabbit - convert your 24:00:00 to 00:00:00 and this solution should work for you

Comment: @Kent, it depends on what OP means. If it is a timestamp then no, it is not valid. But if it means a time range, then it is valid as is 25:00:00 with the meaning of 25 hours elapsed. Anyway, the OP is not clear enough on that aspect.

Comment: No, the OP does **not** need to convert the date into seconds. A `HH:MM:SS` string can be compared successfully character-by-character; there's no reason to make it a number and use a numeric comparison instead.

Comment: Also, why in the world would someone do ```echo $(echo `date -d @$date1`)``` instead of just `date -d "@$date1"`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you need the echo $(echo ... ) otherwise bash tries to recognize the date output as commands. `-date -d @$date1` would give an invalid command error. Please attempt to run the commands before commenting your opinions

Comment: I have. `date -d @$date1` works fine (when `$date1` contains seconds-since-epoch values). "Trying to recognize the date output as commands" only happens if you have that code inside an extra/unnecessary command substitution.

Comment: #date -d @$date1
> date: invalid date `@23:00:00'

Comment: That error message means your `date1` variable doesn't contain the `+%s` version of the timestamp in the first place; it has nothing to do with bash trying to "recognize the date output as commands".

Comment: my apologies, you are correct. I was in the wrong window :P

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string into date to compare, or make use of `awk` to do the comparison:

```
kent$  cat f
09:00:01 > 09:00:00
09:00:01 > 10:00:00
09:00:01 > 24:00:00
09:00:01 > 17:00:00
09:00:01 > 24:00:00

kent$  awk -F ' > ' '{print $0 "  " ( $1>$2? "Yes":"No")}' f
09:00:01 > 09:00:00  Yes
09:00:01 > 10:00:00  No
09:00:01 > 24:00:00  No
09:00:01 > 17:00:00  No
09:00:01 > 24:00:00  No
```

You can do a comparison by checking the returned value:

```
awk -v a="$t1" -v b="$t2" 'BEGIN{print ($1>=$2?"1":"0")}'
```

Comment: *Why* do you assert that the OP needs to do any conversion? `[[ $str1 > $str2 ]]` is a character-by-character string comparison; with the same number of digits and formatting on each side, is there a reason that's expected *not* to work?